# Opera user agent stylesheet is overriding css of input style

Tags: css, browser, opera

I am using picnic.css framework on my project and the input css is overridden by opera user agent style. How can I override this opera styles that has !important. 
My input css:

```
Input, textarea, .select select {
line-height: 1.5;
margin: 0;
height: 2.1em;
padding: .3em .6em;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: .2em;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
width: 100%;
```

}

Opera User agent style sheet looks like this:

```
input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: rgb(250, 255, 189) !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override user agent styles in your custom css file with the !important css property on the selector

Comment: Could you share your custom file css snippets and the Html file

Comment: I found the solution :) it was because the browser saved my email and password that is why i could not change